# What MySQL field type is suited for '%H:%i' (ex. '01:23' and '23:45')?

Tags: mysql

I have a table containing 1440 rows, one for every minute in a day.

What is the best field type?

```
00:00
00:01
...
23:58
23:59
```

Comment: Why not just use datetime? You can always parse out the extra stuff you don't need when querying or at the app layer.

Comment: @MikePurcell, if only the time part needs to be stored then why using datetime unnecessarily?

Comment: I get what your saying, but datetime is already a data type, and you may wind up using the other values down the road as biz reqs dictate. Better to store too much and not need it, than not store enough and need it.

Comment: It's impossible to tell you what field type would be the best since you didn't specify *what the column is for*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Time`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/time.html) datatype to store the value but if it's some duration you are trying to store then I believe better would be store it as `INT` and then you can perform some calculation on it as well.

Comment: That might do. I'm storing the int separately as well. Thanks.